# Get the phone number when someone calls

Tags: python, network-programming, modem, serial-communication, low-level

I'll describe a scenario that I want to implement but I don't know if it is possible with my equipment and my knowledge about this topic.

Suppose, that one calls me on the telephone at home. If I have an appropriate device then I can see his number on the phone device. How, could I get the phone number (using a simple modem) to the computer?

Is there any python library that could work on this ?

Could you propose me some resources from which I can learn some terminology and technical things ?

**EDIT**

I have found this python library https://pypi.org/project/python-gsmmodem/ but it is not related with my problem since I haven't got gsm modem and actually, I don't want to call someone from the computer. I just want to find a way for showing the caller number in the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ideas and some terminology:

- the device attached to a line is serial modem, where serial stands for a method of connection to a computer (port type)
- you can also attach a cellular phone to a computer, term to look for is GSM modem
- a set of low-level commands to manipulate a serial modem is called [AT commands](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtextended4.4/atcommands.html), like pick / send call
- low-level means that you have to learn quite a bit of internals about settings, port, etc - be prepared it can be a bit of a pain. Part of the pain is that people do not use this functionslity as much, so reading  documentation needs care, some things perhaps outdated.
- there us a cloud-based service called Twilio and a high-level python library for it, that makesit easier to send/recieve calls, but parts of the service is paid, it will not help with a localline either

Hope it is good enough for a start.

Update: for determining the caller number you have to look for caller ID capability in your modem, similar to described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20138819/1758363). For program to listen to the the port you wrap it in eternal loop and print the number after a call, for example.

Comment: Also try searching StackOverflow for sending calls, there is much more answers, can help pick up the topic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I have found all of these around the web but most of them (e.g. GSM, Twilio) assume that there is a number and the computer can also makes calls. But, I don't want something like this, I just want to show the caller number to my pc like in my phone device

Comment: Do you have the modem attached already? Or you are just looking what to buy?

Comment: Is this your case: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20138819/1758363

Comment: Please see an update.